# Mongoose finds already deleted documents

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have one endpoint in my api, which deletes one specific document:

```
exports.removeProduct = (req, res) => {
    const productId = req.params.productId
    Product.deleteOne({ _id: productId }, (err) => {
        // handle response
    })
}
```

Since the deleted document isn't in the database anymore, it should have been deleted at this point.
Nevertheless, I retrieve the deleted document when calling this:

```
exports.getUnpublished = (req, res) => {
    var unpublishedProducts = []
    const userId = req.params.userId
    Product.find({ userId: userId, published: false }, (err, products) => {
        products.forEach((product) => {
            if (Number(product.createdAt) === Number(product.updatedAt)) {
                Product.remove({ _id: product._id }).exec();
            } else {
                unpublishedProducts.push(product)
            }
        })
        // handle response
    })
}
```

For explanation: First I find all documents that have the specific `userId` and aren't yet `published`. Afterwards, I loop over all of the found documents and remove all, that have never been updated. All other documents get pushed into the  `unpublishedProducts` array.

Oddly enough, the `unpublishedProducts` array contains documents that have already been deleted.

P.S.: I noticed, that after restarting the server, the deleted documents aren't in the `unpublishedProducts` array anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your product schema by adding a `deleted: {type: Boolean, default: false}` attribute.

On the `removeProduct` you can use

```
Product.updateOne({ _id: productId }, {$set: {deleted: true}}, (result) => {
        // handle response
})
```

to retrieve all undeleted product you can use this query `Product.find({deleted: {$ne: true}})`

Comment: thanks, this is indeed a good idea, but do you know where the issue comes from?

Comment: `unpublishedProducts` is a memory variable, after restarting the server it will be destroyed. so you need to save the unpublishedProducts somewhere, by adding a new collection for unpublishedProducts or by using Redis DB.

Comment: thank you so much! I just did `unpublishedProducts = []` everytime the route gets fired